Need to cut a small cube from a big cube

Hey can someone help me to kind a geberate this marke small cube or cut  small cube from the big cube?
thank u very much. followiing is the code:

How did you define a large cube?

Please post the Mathematica code.

You didn't provide much to go on in terms of how the big cube is defined or how you want to handle the output, but very generally you can use CSGRegion to do this kind of thing:
CSGRegion[
  "Difference", 
  {Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}], Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {.25, .25, .25}]}]


Or
CSGRegion[
  "Difference", 
  {Cuboid[], TranslationTransform[{-.75, -.75, -.75}][Cuboid[]]}]

Or any number of equivalent operations.

Clear["Global`*"];
arrayofcubes = ConstantArray[1, {5, 5, 5}];
arrayofcubes[[1, 5, 1]] = 0; (* remove corner *)
am = ArrayMesh[arrayofcubes
  , DataReversed -> True
  ]



When you have removed cubes as needed, then you can do:
am // DiscretizeRegion


thank u soo much

This creates a small cube at a vertex of the large cube with length 1/4 of the large cube:
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Cube[4], Cube[1.5 {1, -1, -1}]}]


